# Tired light question

Tags: cosmology, electromagnetic-radiation, space-expansion, redshift

How do we arrive at the conclusion that redshifted light from cosmological sources has 'lost' energy during its transit from source to us? If in fact no actual measurement of the energy of the redshifted light is ever made. Either at source or here on earth.
Am I correct in assuming that it is not because energy is observed to be 'lost' in the redshifted light during its transit from source to earth, but rather because the observed change in wavelength was not compatible with the theoretical concept of the photon?

Comment: More on [tired light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22tired+light%22).

Comment: What are these "approximate calculations"?

Comment: "It seems that no calculations of this sort are ever actually made" ─ or maybe they are done, and you simply are not looking at the parts of the technical astrophysics literature where they are reported?

Comment: In response to the questions regarding calculations. Assuming redshift and lost energy is not from expansion then I assumed that if 200-220nm emitted turns to observed to arrive as 400-440 then that's twice the range of wavelength between emitted and observed. Seeing as Emilio admitted that the closest formula for spectral radiance cannot be used. I did the next best option. Which was to simplify and assume I could model this approx. mathematically by calculating K210 +K 220 (emitted) against K410,K420,K430&K440. They both seem to equal. Which suggests that redshift light has not lost energy.

Comment: If I can just clarify a point re Emilios point above about  whether or not calculations were done or referred to. Note that the original question didn't ask how energy is lost under the current BB model, and therefore be answered by supposed calculations in the current literature.  But rather,...why are tired light models rejected as considered to have light lose energy. When in fact this is an assumption that cannot be proven mathematically or measured. As Emilio admitted earlier.

Comment: The measurement is not done using the intensity of the light so we don't need to know the original intensity of the light. It's done by measuring how far known spectral lines have shifted. See for example [How is Doppler redshift of distant galaxies established?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56515/).

Comment: Yes, I understand that the emitted light is redshifted to lower wavelengths in cosmological redshift. What I'm trying to disentangle is how was the conclusion arrived at that the emitted light "lost" energy during transit. K=hc/wavelength is erroneous. It does not take into account the fact that the spectrum has *widened* and reddened due to redshift between emission and observation. I.e. 200-220nm becomes 400-440.

Comment: @N.Tomson Simply count photons.  If the source emits $n$ photons a second then you can detect no more than this number of photons a second (and in fact less, but we don't have to worry about this since we don't need it).  If they have longer wavelengths then the energy flux is necessarily lower.  For this not to be true you would require additional photons to appear along the path between the source and you.

Comment: @tfbThat hilites the reason why I asked the question. We *can't* count the photons leaving. We can only count those arriving already redshifted. So it's impossible to say what the energy E was at emission. You don't seem to understand the question. Tired light is supposedly refuted because it can't explain where the "lost" energy went. But at no time is any energy measured or observed to be lost, only assumed. So critics of tired light shouldn't say, erroneously, that energy is lost. What they should say is that redshift refuted the photon model, unless one erroneously assumes energy is lost.

Comment: @RobJeffries. Thanks for reopening my discussion. But I havent doubled the number of photons! All I have done is show that at the minimum energies allowed by Planck a range of wavelengths of 220-240 nm has less energy than a range of wavelengths between 210-250nm. Don't forget, it is you who assumes that redshifting a source to a longer and wider range loses energy . Not me.

Comment: @N.Tomson You can indeed count the photons leaving, unless you assume that photons are created or destroyed between the source and the observer.  For the energy flux to be the same with photons of lower energy it must necessarily be the case that photons were created in the path  between source and observer.

Comment: You do not understand the difference between assumption and observation. You measure the energies on arrival, assume these counts are photons. And then *assume* that these counts equate to imaginary photons leaving the source. You also forget an important part of scientific procedure. If an observation is made that refutes theory ( redshift was not compatible with photon model) then said theory has been refuted... Unless you make up another imaginary theory (BBT) to allow for an imaginary energy loss to be predicted, to then validate the original discredited model(photon model)

Comment: As I mentioned to a previous, now deleted(?)comment,the SN1a data *can* be fit to a non expanding z=0 model using only a stretch factor s, as long as s is <1.15. (Knop and Blondin *also* apply stretch factors in addition to cosmological expansion 1+z of up to s< 1.15) For instance, all 11 of the supernovas from Knop (2003) &Blondin can fit to a non dilated z=0 template to prove that SN1a data *does also fit* a non expanding model, contrary to myth, with most as good if not better fits to template than the BBT model. Examples include 1997eq(s=1.10),1998as(s=0.99),1998ay(s=1.15),1998be(s=1.08)

Answer (score -3):

> In the early part of the twentieth century, Slipher, Hubble and others made the first measurements of the redshifts and blueshifts of galaxies beyond the Milky Way. They initially interpreted these redshifts and blueshifts as due to random motions, but later (***1927***) Hubble discovered a rough correlation between the increasing redshifts and the increasing distance of galaxies. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift#Expansion_of_space).

Measurements of the red and the blue shift in a gravitational field are done ***1959*** in the [Pound–Rebka experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment). The results of this experiment explained by the influence of gravitational field on the photon: "When the photon travels through a gravitational field, its frequency and therefore its energy will change due to the gravitational redshift."(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound-Rebka_experiment)

Another possible interpretation for this experiment is that if the sources are located in points with different gravitational potential they photons at different frequencies. For example a hydrogen line coming from the sun - measured on the earth - is red shifted and a hydrogen line coming from the moon (where someone has to carry out such an experiment) with its smaller gravitation has to be blue shifted.

> How do we arrive at the conclusion that redshifted light from cosmological sources has 'lost' energy during its transit from source to us?

Photons don’t lose energy between their emission and receiving. Einstein wrote:

> Light "... consists of a finite number of energy quanta which are localized at points in space, which **move without dividing, and which can only be produced and absorbed as complete units.**"[A. Einstein Concerning an Heuristic Point of View Toward the Emission and Transformation of Light](http://www.esfm2005.ipn.mx/ESFM_Images/paper1.pdf)

Comment: You ignore the fact that the photon model as described by Einstein, was refuted by the observations that light appeared to change wavelength over distance. It's also worth noting that no evidence was seen that energy was lost between source and observor. (That's why I asked the initial question. I knew from my calculations using planks equation that no energy seemed to be lost, but I wanted to see if there were calculations that could show this. As you can see none were offered. )This imaginary energy loss was made up to allow the photon model to survive refutation from redshift.

Comment: N.Tomson Perhaps I was not clear enough with my answer. If photons get emitted (for example from a hydrogen atom) their energy and wavelength depends from the gravitational potential. Nothing gets lost for redshifted photons nor gets added for blueshifted photons. Simply the photons left the atom in dependence from the gravitational potential with different energies than that from the emission on earth.

Comment: “by the observations that light appeared to change wavelength over distance.”is an interpretation. A fact it would be if for blueshifted light the needed energy has to be sucked ... from what? A photon does not gain not lose energy durin* it’s travel.