# distinguishing redshift from star's color

Tags: stars, doppler-effect

How do scientists find out the true color of the star's light as well as the true doppler shift (relative speed)? Seems to me you wouldn't know how to separate out those 2 values.

Comment: Related, and possibly a duplicate: [How is Doppler redshift of distant galaxies established?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56515/how-is-doppler-redshift-of-distant-galaxies-established)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spectroscopy is done on the starlight. Say we look for hydrogen lines. We know where they’ll appear in the spectrum of laboratory hydrogen. If the starlight is redshifted then **all** the hydrogen lines will be shifted by the **same** amount. As can be seen in an example spectrum below.

[image]

Once the shift is quantified, we can work back what the unshifted spectrum of the star would look like.